# Moving element intersecting static element in CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

[Video demo](https://streamable.com/evfy37)

I'm trying to make a rip-off pacman(ish) game for a project using HTML, CSS and Javascript. Check the attached video for reference. The idea is: whenever one of the food elements will intersect the pacman element (ie. get eaten), the score will increase by one. And whenever a food element gets out of the viewport without going through the pacman element, the player will lose 1 life. I tried implementing this with the Intersection Observer API by observing the food elements as target and making the pacman element the root. But that didn't work.

```
const obsCB1 = function (entries, observer) {
  point++;
  console.log(point);
};
const obsOptions1 = {
  root: pacman,
  threshold: 0.01,
};
const obs1 = new IntersectionObserver(obsCB1, obsOptions1);
obs1.observe(f1);
```

(The food element initially starts from outside the viewport to the right and moves to the left using translateX in an infinite loop)
The callback was called once at the start even when f1 didn't intersect pacman. And the point didn't change afterwards. How can I implement this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming both pacmen and the dots are circles, I guess the best is to calculate the distance between to center and check if it less the sum of radiuses

```js
const board = document.querySelector('#board');
const score = board.querySelector('#score-val');
let dots = [];
function updateScore(x){score.innerText = +score.innerText+x}
function Dot(){
  this.SPEED = (.008 + Math.random()/1000) * window.innerHeight;
  this.RADIUS = .02 * window.innerHeight;
  this.el = document.createElement('span');
  this.el.style = `display: inline-block;width:${2*this.RADIUS}px;height:${2*this.RADIUS}px;position:absolute;left:${window.innerWidth}px;top:${Math.random()*(window.innerHeight-2*this.RADIUS)}px;border-radius:50%;background-color: red;`;
  board.appendChild(this.el);
  dots.push(this);
  this.remove = () => {
    dots = dots.filter(d => d!== this);
    this.el.remove();
  }
  this.move = () => {
    this.el.style.left = parseFloat(this.el.style.left)-this.SPEED+'px';
    if(pacmen.isCollapse(this)){
      this.remove();
      updateScore(1);
    } else 
    if(parseFloat(this.el.style.left)<0) { this.remove();
    updateScore(-1);
    }
  }
}
function Pacmen(){
  this.SPEED = .05 * window.innerHeight;
  this.RADIUS = .07 * window.innerHeight;
  this.el = board.querySelector('#pacmen');
  this.el.style.left=0;
  this.el.style.top=0;
  this.el.width=this.RADIUS*2;
  this.el.height=this.RADIUS*2;
  this.move = x => {
  this.el.style.top = Math.min(window.innerHeight-this.RADIUS*2, Math.max(0, parseFloat(this.el.style.top)+x*this.SPEED))+'px';
  }
  window.addEventListener('keydown', (e)=> {
  switch(e.key){
    case 'ArrowDown':
      e.preventDefault();
      this.move(1);
      break;
    case 'ArrowUp':
      e.preventDefault();
      this.move(-1);
      break;
  }
  });
  this.isCollapse = (dot) => {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(parseFloat(this.el.style.left + this.RADIUS)-parseFloat(dot.el.style.left + dot.RADIUS),2)+Math.pow(parseFloat(this.el.style.top + this.RADIUS)-parseFloat(dot.el.style.top + dot.RADIUS),2)) <= this.RADIUS + dot.RADIUS
  }
}
const pacmen = new Pacmen();
function frame(){
  dots.forEach(dot =>dot.move());
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}
setInterval(()=>new Dot(), 1000);
frame();
```

```css
html,body{padding:0;margin:0}
#board{
display:block;
width:100%;
height:100vh;
background-color:black;
position: relative;
overflow:hidden;
}
#pacmen {
  position: absolute;
}
#score{
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="board">
<img id="pacmen" src="data:image/gif;base64,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"/>
<h3 id="score">Score: <span id="score-val">0</span><h3>
</div>
```